# How to update GetBundles in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I originally installed GetBundles using [Trey Piepmeier's instructions](http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/02/25/installing-getbundles-on-a-fresh-copy-of-textmate/). Afterwards, I installed all TextMate bundles using GetBundles. I noticed that my copy of GetBundles was old, so I did the following:

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/
```

When I restarted TextMate and opened GetBundles, a dialog box popped up asking me to select the source for many—if not all—of my bundles. I can't remember which version of the Django bundle I installed or numerous others.

Is there anyway to update GetBundles without having it lose its head on the sources?

Comment: Is there any way you could make this question as answered if it worked for you?  I'm curious.

Comment: @Brandon — I was hoping for a better solution that didn't involve me having to remember to copy & paste the preferences file prior to updating GetBundles. I won't hold out forever though. If you're answer is what it actually takes, then I'll accept after a few more weeks. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in TextMate click Bundles->GetBundles->Edit Preferences File.  Either copy the data or back up the file to another location.  Then update GetBundles.  Now, select Edit Preferences File again, and paste that info back in.  That should update the GetBundles bundle while maintaining its own data about which bundles you have installed.

Here are a couple sample lines from mine:
        0B296803-7D51-11D9-859D-000D93B6E43C
        https://github.com/textmate/todo.tmbundle/tarball/master
        0D39D7BD-CD02-48EF-BB9C-2210BFFC5AD7
        http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/CTags.tmbundle
        385A8908-0733-408E-AFA5-9576D2E3A16B
        https://github.com/textmate/mail.tmbundle/tarball/master
        4675A940-6227-11D9-BFB1-000D93589AF6
        https://github.com/textmate/c.tmbundle/tarball/master

As you can see, it keeps track of the repository info, etc.  The file itself is com.macromates.textmate.getbundles.plist and is located in ~/Library/Preferences.

I hope this helps.