# How can I fix permissions for bundles or Subversion in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

When I try to use `GetBundles` to update my `TextMate` bundles, "Parsing Local Bundles" appears and the progress wheel spins endlessly (e.g. >20 minutes). Reading the Help manual for `GetBundles` suggests that this might be a permissions error.

In line with this, typing at the command line the commands from this question ( [How to update GetBundles in TextMate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429543/how-to-update-getbundles-in-textmate) ),

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/
```

produces this response:

```
Can't make directory 'GetBundles.tmbundle': Permission denied
```

Can I fix permissions somehow, to make `GetBundles` work properly, if that's my problem? Thanks!

update: I seem to have `TextMate/Bundles/` in both my user user Library and the higher level Library. Could that be my problem? And if so, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORIGINAL RESPONSE:
You need to remove the trailing slash from `GetBundles.tmbundle/` so it reads like a file and not a directory: `GetBundles.tmbundle` <- incorrect (I misunderstood the question - apologies)

UPDATE:
I think the mistake (in your command as typed above anyway) is that spaces need escaping or the path needs quoting in your 'cd' command. So, from a fresh Terminal session (i.e. from your user Home directory) try quoting the path:

```
cd "Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/"
```

then

```
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/
```

Try that, and post the exact terminal readout here...

Comment: Okay, thanks, but that particular command also produces the same  permissions error without the trailing slash.

Comment: what do you see with get info on the Bundles directory under Sharing & Permissions? You (the account owner) should be able to read *and* write to it...

Comment: The above still applies, but I have a script here that you might try: https://gist.github.com/1000478

Comment: The permissions are Read & Write for my user account on all the folders and files I checked in Application Support/TextMate/Bundles

Comment: I ran ./tm_bundle.sh Shell Script and got back: -bash: ./tm_bundle.sh: Permission denied

Comment: You need to make the script executable - open terminal, and (if you put it in your 'Home' directory) do `chmod +x tm_bundle.sh`

Comment: Thanks again for the help -- but it goes into an infinite loop, repeating: Changing to your Bundles directory...
Checking out bundle: Shell Script ...
svn: URL 'http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Shell%20Script.tmbundle' doesn't exist

Comment: Apologies - I missed the fact that you're not getting a *specific* bundle - my script won't work! See addition to my original reply above.